# data duplication in sqlite with android app

Tags: android, sqlite

i am getting information from user in sqlite database.
But when i insert same record which is already in database it is added again.
how i can stop duplication of record in sqlite. I am developing this in android.
I am using mobile number as primary key. still it add that record in database.
Please suggest me appropriate solutions.
Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2):

Be aware of the limitations of REPLACE or INSERT OR REPLACE as these will overwrite any custom data your app user has added to these rows in the database - it is not as advanced as UPSERT in other SQL databases.

As mentioned in a previous post you really need to identify what the primary key could be and use this information to either update old data or to remove an old row before inserting the fresh one.

If this is not possible then you could always DELETE FROM my_table or DROP my_table before running the insertions so that there will be no duplicates. This will (for better or worse) also make sure that data that is missing from new imports is not left lying around in your app.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have set your phone number as Primary Key at the time you created the table.

for example:

```
String query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PhoneBook ("+
"TelNum VARCHAR(100) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,"+
"Address TEXT);";

db.execSQL(query);
```

and in case you want to enforce foreign keys defined in your table then call the following method before doing anything in your database

```
db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;"); //enforcing FK
```

Answer (score 0):

Use REPLACE INTO keyword:

```
REPLACE INTO my_table (pk_id, col1) VALUES (5, '123');
```

This automatically identifies the primary key and finds a matching row to update, inserting a new one if none is found.